# How to get the screen logs of a oracle VM

Tags: linux, stdout

When I start an oracle VM with Linux operating system I want to get the standard output, i.e whatever is coming in the screen. Is there any tool or is there any way to get that so that I can check that file for some other purpose.

Basically I need that output to check some particular keyword which is coming or not, like `Do you want to continue (y/n)`.
[image]

I need a file where whatever is coming on the screen is redirected to that file.

Comment: @jasonwryan, cuonglm, clm : Provide me the required permission to add a photo in this post i can explain better. 
if you don't know the answer don't delete the post, rather say u don't have the capability to answer this level of question or you have not faced such a high level of question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Serial_redirect you can use a serial port for that:

Edit your VM settings, add a serial port (COM1) and set the port mode to raw. As port/file path choose /tmp/ttyVBOX.

Start the VM and at the grub boot menu choose <kbd>e</kbd> to edit and navigate to the line that begins with kernel. Append

```
console=ttyS0 console=tty0 ignore_loglevel
```

From another terminal session on the host machine, execute `tail -f /tmp/ttyVBOX`

Now, from the VM, enter <kbd>b</kbd> to boot the VM guest OS. The output should now be visible in your terminal.

To make this permanent for a guest OS so you don't have to edit the kernel lines, edit the grub menu.lst file somewhere in /boot/grub/menu.lst (for grub v1) or follow the steps in https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter for grub v2

Once you are inside your guest OS you can start ssh to connect to the host OS with port forwarding:

If you use the default network mode of NAT you should be able to use

```
ssh -L 2222:localhost:22 10.0.2.2
```

This will start a SSH session to the Host OS and redirect traffic from the Host OS port 2222 to the guest OS on port 22.

From the Host OS you should be able to use

```
ssh -p 2222 user@localhost
```

which will in fact start a SSH session to the guest OS.

This way you will have both text mode for console (while booting) as for terminal sessions (using SSH) that will allow you to copy text and do your stuff with it.